# Erro ao fazer commit push no Webstorm

Tags: git, github, webstorm

Ao tentar fazer o commit push de um projeto ele traz a seguinte mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que pode estar acotencedo?

Comment: Use `git fetch`, depois tenta fazer o *commit* novamente.

Comment: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD